# Unable to connect to chef server

Tags: chef, knife, chef-server

I have a Chef server running on AWS. I am able to connect to it via web browser and see the web ui from my machine which isn't the ec2. But when I bootstrap the node, also a ec2, it fails to connect to the server after 5 attempts. If I copy and the exact url that it is trying to connect to from the error message and paste it into my browser it works. If I curl the url from the Chef server it works. If I curl the url or ping the IP from the node, it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out I had the Security group on the server set up to only accept Https  requests from my IP :/

Comment: Feel free to post that an an answer and then accept it so this Q doesn't sit unanswered for all of eternity. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I had the Security group on the server set up to only accept Https requests from my IP :/